# ViewPager and fragments — what's the right way to store fragment's state?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Fragments seem to be very nice for separation of UI logic into some modules. But along with `ViewPager` its lifecycle is still misty to me. So Guru thoughts are badly needed!

#### Edit

See dumb solution below ;-)

### Scope

Main activity has a `ViewPager` with fragments. Those fragments could implement a little bit different logic for other (submain) activities, so the fragments' data is filled via a callback interface inside the activity. And everything works fine on first launch, but!...

### Problem

When the activity gets recreated (e.g. on orientation change) so do the `ViewPager`'s fragments. The code (you'll find below) says that every time the activity is created I try to create a new `ViewPager` fragments adapter the same as fragments (maybe this is the problem) but FragmentManager already has all these fragments stored somewhere (where?) and starts the recreation mechanism for those. So the recreation mechanism calls the "old" fragment's onAttach, onCreateView, etc. with my callback interface call for initiating data via the Activity's implemented method. But this method points to the newly created fragment which is created via the Activity's onCreate method.

### Issue

Maybe I'm using wrong patterns but even Android 3 Pro book doesn't have much about it. So, **please**, give me one-two punch and point out how to do it the right way. Many thanks!

### Code

*Main Activity*

```
public class DashboardActivity extends BasePagerActivity implements OnMessageListActionListener {

private MessagesFragment mMessagesFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Logger.d("Dash onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_container);
    new DefaultToolbar(this);

    // create fragments to use
    mMessagesFragment = new MessagesFragment();
    mStreamsFragment = new StreamsFragment();

    // set titles and fragments for view pager
    Map<String, Fragment> screens = new LinkedHashMap<String, Fragment>();
    screens.put(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.dashboard_title_dumb), new DumbFragment());
    screens.put(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.dashboard_title_messages), mMessagesFragment);

    // instantiate view pager via adapter
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new BasePagerAdapter(screens, getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    // set title indicator
    TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_titles);
    indicator.setViewPager(mPager, 1);

}

/* set of fragments callback interface implementations */

@Override
public void onMessageInitialisation() {

    Logger.d("Dash onMessageInitialisation");
    if (mMessagesFragment != null)
        mMessagesFragment.loadLastMessages();
}

@Override
public void onMessageSelected(Message selectedMessage) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StreamActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Message.class.getName(), selectedMessage);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

*BasePagerActivity aka helper*

```
public class BasePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

BasePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
}
```

*Adapter*

```
public class BasePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {

private Map<String, Fragment> mScreens;

public BasePagerAdapter(Map<String, Fragment> screenMap, FragmentManager fm) {

    super(fm);
    this.mScreens = screenMap;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return mScreens.values().toArray(new Fragment[mScreens.size()])[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mScreens.size();
}

@Override
public String getTitle(int position) {

    return mScreens.keySet().toArray(new String[mScreens.size()])[position];
}

// hack. we don't want to destroy our fragments and re-initiate them after
@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

*Fragment*

```
public class MessagesFragment extends ListFragment {

private boolean mIsLastMessages;

private List<Message> mMessagesList;
private MessageArrayAdapter mAdapter;

private LoadMessagesTask mLoadMessagesTask;
private OnMessageListActionListener mListener;

// define callback interface
public interface OnMessageListActionListener {
    public void onMessageInitialisation();
    public void onMessageSelected(Message selectedMessage);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // setting callback
    mListener = (OnMessageListActionListener) activity;
    mIsLastMessages = activity instanceof DashboardActivity;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container);
    mProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_progress, null);
    mEmptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nodata, null);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // instantiate loading task
    mLoadMessagesTask = new LoadMessagesTask();

    // instantiate list of messages
    mMessagesList = new ArrayList<Message>();
    mAdapter = new MessageArrayAdapter(getActivity(), mMessagesList);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mListener.onMessageInitialisation();
    super.onResume();
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Message selectedMessage = (Message) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    mListener.onMessageSelected(selectedMessage);
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}

/* public methods to load messages from host acitivity, etc... */
}
```

### Solution

The dumb solution is to save the fragments inside onSaveInstanceState (of host Activity) with putFragment and get them inside onCreate via getFragment. But I still have a strange feeling that things shouldn't work like that... See code below:

```
    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .putFragment(outState, MessagesFragment.class.getName(), mMessagesFragment);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Logger.d("Dash onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    // create fragments to use
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mMessagesFragment = (MessagesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                savedInstanceState, MessagesFragment.class.getName());
                StreamsFragment.class.getName());
    }
    if (mMessagesFragment == null)
        mMessagesFragment = new MessagesFragment();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wonder now: should I use a very different approach or try to save fragments of main activity (Dashboard) via onSavedInstancestate to use them in onCreate(). Is there a proper way to save those fragments and get them from bundle in onCreate? They don't seem to be parcelable...

Comment: 2nd approach works — see "Sulution". But it seems to be an ugly piece of code, isn't is?

Comment: For the sake of the effort to cleanup the Android tag (details here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100529/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag ), would you mind posting your solution as an answer and marking it as the selected one?  That way it won't show up as an unanswered question :)

Comment: yeah, think it's OK. Hoped for smth better than mine...

Comment: Does the dumb solution even work? It gives me a null pointer exception..

Comment: Dumb solution (the one with saveOnInstance) really works, and might I add, I spent hours and hours debugging the issue I had with fragments on some very specific use case. It turns out it boils down to this one, and resolved it using this solution. Saved my day

Answer (score 457, accepted):

When the `FragmentPagerAdapter` adds a fragment to the FragmentManager, it uses a special tag based on the particular position that the fragment will be placed. `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int position)` is only called when a fragment for that position does not exist. After rotating, Android will notice that it already created/saved a fragment for this particular position and so it simply tries to reconnect with it with `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()`, instead of creating a new one. All of this comes free when using the `FragmentPagerAdapter` and is why it is usual to have your fragment initialisation code inside the `getItem(int)` method.

Even if we were not using a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, it is not a good idea to create a new fragment every single time in `Activity.onCreate(Bundle)`. As you have noticed, when a fragment is added to the FragmentManager, it will be recreated for you after rotating and there is no need to add it again. Doing so is a common cause of errors when working with fragments.

A usual approach when working with fragments is this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    CustomFragment fragment;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        fragment = (CustomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("customtag");
    } else {
        fragment = new CustomFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, "customtag").commit(); 
    }

    ...

}
```

When using a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, we relinquish fragment management to the adapter, and do not have to perform the above steps. By default, it will only preload one Fragment in front and behind the current position (although it does not destroy them unless you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`). This is controlled by [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29). Because of this, directly calling methods on the fragments outside of the adapter is not guaranteed to be valid, because they may not even be alive.

To cut a long story short, your solution to use `putFragment` to be able to get a reference afterwards is not so crazy, and not so unlike the normal way to use fragments anyway (above). It is difficult to obtain a reference otherwise because the fragment is added by the adapter, and not you personally. Just make sure that the `offscreenPageLimit` is high enough to load your desired fragments at all times, since you rely on it being present. This bypasses lazy loading capabilities of the ViewPager, but seems to be what you desire for your application.

Another approach is to override `FragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(View, int)` and save a reference to the fragment returned from the super call before returning it (it has the logic to find the fragment, if already present).

For a fuller picture, have a look at some of the source of [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.java?av=f) (short) and [ViewPager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java?av=f) (long).

Comment: Loved the last part. Had a cache for the fragments and moved the put in the cache logic inside the `FragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(View, int)`. Finally fixed a long lasting bug that only appears in the rotation/config change and  was driving me crazy...

Comment: This fixed an issue I was having on rotation change. It maybe that I just can't see for looking, but is this documented? i.e. using the tag to recover from a previous state? It maybe an obvious answer, but I'm fairly new to Android development.

Comment: In my case, I always set OffscreenPageLimit to 3, and that's the maximum fragment my single PagerAdapter have. I'm just wondering if this consumed more RAM... I sometime still have NPE when using getSherlockActivity() in SherlockFragment.

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant It is the id of the container (e.g. a FrameLayout) to which the Fragment is to be added.

Comment: btw, for me it was `FragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)` rather than `FragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(View, int)`.

Comment: Btw do you know which (if any) fragment lifecycle method is called when the fragment gets swiped off the screen? Is it `onDetach()`, or something else?

Comment: I think I found the answer: nothing! No lifecycle callback is invoked when swiping between two panes on a PageViewer. Both fragments that are being swiped between are 'resumed'. What a bummer! Do you know of any other callback that would indicate that transition?

Comment: @jegesh You could set an OnPageChangeListener on the ViewPager to listen for page changes. You could also override Fragment.setUserVisibleHint (this is called with 'true' whenever the Fragment is made visible in the ViewPager, and with 'false' when disappearing).

Comment: In my case i have a fragment that is hosting `ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter`. This **fragment** replaces the previous *fragment* with `addToBackStack()`. When first time started i can see the layout of the child fragments i.e inside `ViewPager`. I press back and then again start This fragment again i see no Layout until swipe to end and then come back to first. What i can see is Adapter is not releasing the references even the fragment is removed. Any idea/help?

Comment: @antonyt Could you take a look at this question about ViewPager? Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937250/viewpager-on-a-view-added-by-windowmanager-getting-java-lang-illegalargumentexc/27937559

Comment: The section about overriding `FragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)` deserves a separate header or something because it's very helpful. If you need to save a reference to the returned Fragments this is a perfect spot to do it. Also you can grab a reference to the `Fragment`'s `tag` (the one that `FragmentPagerAdapter` creates automatically) in this method as well.

Comment: I wonder if the section about overriding `FragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)` might be a bad idea. In principle, when the activity is stopped, fragments could get destroyed any time and re-created when needed, while the `ViewPagerAdapter` and the activity still live. I think there is no guarantee this won't fail, if not now, maybe in future android versions.

Comment: What about when I use a library which uses ViewPager and FragmentPageAdapter and does not expose access to them? Is there anything I can do in my Fragment to make sure it restores state after orientation change?

Answer (score 37):

I want to offer a solution that expands on `antonyt`'s [**wonderful answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646622/708906) and mention of overriding `FragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(View, int)` to save references to created `Fragments` so you can do work on them later. This should also work with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`; see notes for details.

---

Here's a simple example of how to get a reference to the `Fragments` returned by `FragmentPagerAdapter` that doesn't rely on the internal `tags` set on the `Fragments`. The key is to override [**`instantiateItem()`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java?av=f#83) and save references in there *instead* of in `getItem()`.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private FragmentA m1stFragment;
    private FragmentB m2ndFragment;

    // other code in your Activity...

    private class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        // other code in your custom FragmentPagerAdapter...

        public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // Do NOT try to save references to the Fragments in getItem(),
            // because getItem() is not always called. If the Fragment
            // was already created then it will be retrieved from the FragmentManger
            // and not here (i.e. getItem() won't be called again).
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentA();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentB();
                default:
                    // This should never happen. Always account for each position above
                    return null;
            }
        }

        // Here we can finally safely save a reference to the created
        // Fragment, no matter where it came from (either getItem() or
        // FragmentManger). Simply save the returned Fragment from
        // super.instantiateItem() into an appropriate reference depending
        // on the ViewPager position.
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            // save the appropriate reference depending on position
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    m1stFragment = (FragmentA) createdFragment;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    m2ndFragment = (FragmentB) createdFragment;
                    break;
            }
            return createdFragment;
        }
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // do work on the referenced Fragments, but first check if they
        // even exist yet, otherwise you'll get an NPE.

        if (m1stFragment != null) {
            // m1stFragment.doWork();
        }

        if (m2ndFragment != null) {
            // m2ndFragment.doSomeWorkToo();
        }
    }
}
```

**or** if you prefer to work with `tags` instead of class member variables/references to the `Fragments` you can also grab the `tags` set by `FragmentPagerAdapter` in the same manner:
NOTE: this doesn't apply to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` since it doesn't set `tags` when creating its `Fragments`.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    // get the tags set by FragmentPagerAdapter
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            String firstTag = createdFragment.getTag();
            break;
        case 1:
            String secondTag = createdFragment.getTag();
            break;
    }
    // ... save the tags somewhere so you can reference them later
    return createdFragment;
}
```

Note that this method does NOT rely on mimicking the internal `tag` set by `FragmentPagerAdapter` and instead uses proper APIs for retrieving them. This way even if the `tag` changes in future versions of the `SupportLibrary` you'll still be safe.

---

**Don't forget** that depending on the design of your `Activity`, the `Fragments` you're trying to work on may or may not exist yet, so you have to account for that by doing `null` checks before using your references.

**Also, if instead** you're working with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, then you don't want to keep hard references to your `Fragments` because you might have many of them and hard references would unnecessarily keep them in memory. Instead save the `Fragment` references in `WeakReference` variables instead of standard ones. Like this:

```
WeakReference<Fragment> m1stFragment = new WeakReference<Fragment>(createdFragment);
// ...and access them like so
Fragment firstFragment = m1stFragment.get();
if (firstFragment != null) {
    // reference hasn't been cleared yet; do work...
}
```

Comment: on memory shortage android might ask the FragmentManager to destroy unused fragments, right? If I am right, your second version will work, the first might fail. (Don't know if current android versions do this, but it seems we have to expect that.)

Comment: what about creating a `FragmetPagerAdapter` in onCreate of Activity on every screen rotation. Is this wrong because it may bypass reusing already added fragments in `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: Overriding `instantiateItem()` is the way to go; this helped me handle screen rotations, and retrieving my existing Fragment instances once the Activity and Adapter were resumed; I left myself comments in the code as a reminder: 

After rotation, `getItem()` is NOT invoked; only this method `instantiateItem()` gets called. The super implementation for `instantiateItem()` actually re-attaches fragments after rotation (as necessary), instead of instantiating new instances!

Comment: I'm getting null pointer on  `Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem..` in first solution.

Comment: After hunting through all the various duplicate/variant iterations of this problem, this was the best solution. (Cross-referenced from another Q with a more relevant title, so thank you for that!)

Answer (score 18):

I found another relatively easy solution for your question.

As you can see from the [FragmentPagerAdapter source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java#FragmentPagerAdapter.makeFragmentName%28int,int%29), the fragments managed by `FragmentPagerAdapter` store in the `FragmentManager` under the tag generated using:

```
String tag="android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
```

The `viewId` is the `container.getId()`, the `container` is your `ViewPager` instance. The `index` is the position of the fragment. Hence you can save the object id to the `outState`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("viewpagerid" , mViewPager.getId() );
}

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        viewpagerid=savedInstanceState.getInt("viewpagerid", -1 );  

    MyFragmentPagerAdapter titleAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager() , this);        
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if (viewpagerid != -1 ){
        mViewPager.setId(viewpagerid);
    }else{
        viewpagerid=mViewPager.getId();
    }
    mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
```

If you want to communicate with this fragment, you can get if from `FragmentManager`, such as:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewpagerid + ":0")
```

Comment: hmmm I dont think this is a good way to go as your replying on an internal tag naming convention that is by no means going to stay the same forever.

Comment: For those looking for a solution that doesn't rely on the internal `tag`, consider trying [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29288093/708906).

Answer (score 16):

I want to offer an alternate solution for perhaps a slightly different case, since many of my searches for answers kept leading me to this thread.

**My case**
- I'm creating/adding pages dynamically and sliding them into a ViewPager, but when rotated (onConfigurationChange) I end up with a new page because of course OnCreate is called again.  But I want to keep reference to all the pages that were created prior to the rotation.

**Problem**
- I don't have unique identifiers for each fragment I create, so the only way to reference was to somehow store references in an Array to be restored after the rotation/configuration change.

**Workaround**
- The key concept was to have the Activity (which displays the Fragments) also manage the array of references to existing Fragments, since this activity can utilize Bundles in onSaveInstanceState

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

So within this Activity, I declare a private member to track the open pages

```
private List<Fragment> retainedPages = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
```

This is updated everytime onSaveInstanceState is called and restored in onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    retainedPages = _adapter.exportList();
    outState.putSerializable("retainedPages", (Serializable) retainedPages);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

...so once it's stored, it can be retrieved...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        retainedPages = (List<Fragment>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("retainedPages");
    }
    _mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    _adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager());
    if (retainedPages.size() > 0) {
        _adapter.importList(retainedPages);
    }
    _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
    _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(_adapter.getCount()-1);
}
```

These were the necessary changes to the main activity, and so I needed the members and methods within my FragmentPagerAdapter for this to work, so within

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
```

an identical construct (as shown above in MainActivity )

```
private List<Fragment> _pages = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
```

and this syncing (as used above in onSaveInstanceState) is supported specifically by the methods

```
public List<Fragment> exportList() {
    return _pages;
}

public void importList(List<Fragment> savedPages) {
    _pages = savedPages;
}
```

And then finally, in the fragment class

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment
```

in order for all this to work, there were two changes, first

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment implements Serializable
```

and then adding this to onCreate so Fragments aren't destroyed

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

I'm still in the process of wrapping my head around Fragments and Android life cycle, so caveat here is there may be redundancies/inefficiencies in this method.  But it works for me and I hope might be helpful for others with cases similar to mine.

Comment: +1 for setRetainInstance(true) - the black magic I was looking for!

Comment: It was even easier by using FragmentStatePagerAdapter (v13). 
Which deal for you with the state restore and release.

Comment: Clear description and very nice solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

My solution is very rude but works: being my fragments dynamically created from retained data, I simply remove all fragment from the `PageAdapter` before calling `super.onSaveInstanceState()` and then recreate them on activity creation:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("viewpagerpos", mViewPager.getCurrentItem() );
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.removeAllfragments();
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

You can't remove them in `onDestroy()`, otherwise you get this exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException:` Can not perform this action after `onSaveInstanceState`

Here the code in the page adapter:

```
public void removeAllfragments()
{
    if ( mFragmentList != null ) {
        for ( Fragment fragment : mFragmentList ) {
            mFm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        }
        mFragmentList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I only save the current page and restore it in `onCreate()`, after the fragments have been created.

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem( savedInstanceState.getInt("viewpagerpos", 0 ) );
```

Comment: I don't know why, but notifyDataSetChanged(); causes app to crash

Answer (score 4):

What is that `BasePagerAdapter`?  You should use one of the standard pager adapters -- either `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, depending on whether you want Fragments that are no longer needed by the `ViewPager` to either be kept around (the former) or have their state saved (the latter) and re-created if needed again.

Sample code for using `ViewPager` can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Samples)

It is true that the management of fragments in a view pager across activity instances is a little complicated, because the `FragmentManager` in the framework takes care of saving the state and restoring any active fragments that the pager has made.  All this really means is that the adapter when initializing needs to make sure it re-connects with whatever restored fragments there are.  You can look at the code for `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to see how this is done.

Comment: BasePagerAdapter code is available in my question. As one can see it simply extends FragmentPagerAdapter for purpose of implementing [TitleProvider](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). So everything's already been working with android dev suggested approach.

Comment: I wasn't aware of "FragmentStatePagerAdapter". You saved me literally hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is having issues with their FragmentStatePagerAdapter not properly restoring the state of its fragments...ie...new Fragments are being created by the FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of it restoring them from state...

Make sure you call `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()` BEFORE you call `ViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentStatePagerAdapter)`

Upon calling `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()`...the ViewPager will **immediately** look to its adapter and try to get its fragments.  This could happen before the ViewPager has a chance to restore the Fragments from savedInstanceState(thus creating new Fragments that can't be re-initialized from SavedInstanceState because they're new).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this simple and elegant solution. It assumes that the activity is responsible for creating the Fragments, and the Adapter just serves them.

This is the adapter's code (nothing weird here, except for the fact that `mFragments` is a list of fragments maintained by the Activity)

```
class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        TabFragment fragment = (TabFragment)mFragments.get(position);
        return fragment.getTitle();
    }
}
```

The whole problem of this thread is getting a reference of the "old" fragments, so I use this code in the Activity's onCreate.

```
    if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()!=null) {
            for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                mFragments.add(fragment);
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course you can further fine tune this code if needed, for example making sure the fragments are instances of a particular class.

Answer (score 0):

To get the fragments after orientation change you have to use the .getTag().

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + positionOfItemInViewPager)
```

For a bit more handling i wrote my own ArrayList for my PageAdapter to get the fragment by viewPagerId and the FragmentClass at any Position:

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements Serializable {
private final String logTAG = MyPageAdapter.class.getName() + ".";

private ArrayList<MyPageBuilder> fragmentPages;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<MyPageBuilder> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    fragmentPages = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragmentPages.get(position).getFragment();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return this.fragmentPages.get(position).getPageTitle();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragmentPages.size();
}


public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    //benötigt, damit bei notifyDataSetChanged alle Fragemnts refrehsed werden

    Log.d(logTAG, object.getClass().getName());
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
    return getItem(position);
}

public String getTag(int position, int viewPagerId) {
    //getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.shares_detail_activity_viewpager + ":" + myViewPager.getCurrentItem())

    return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + position;
}

public MyPageBuilder getPageBuilder(String pageTitle, int icon, int selectedIcon, Fragment frag) {
    return new MyPageBuilder(pageTitle, icon, selectedIcon, frag);
}


public static class MyPageBuilder {

    private Fragment fragment;

    public Fragment getFragment() {
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    private String pageTitle;

    public String getPageTitle() {
        return pageTitle;
    }

    public void setPageTitle(String pageTitle) {
        this.pageTitle = pageTitle;
    }

    private int icon;

    public int getIconUnselected() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIconUnselected(int iconUnselected) {
        this.icon = iconUnselected;
    }

    private int iconSelected;

    public int getIconSelected() {
        return iconSelected;
    }

    public void setIconSelected(int iconSelected) {
        this.iconSelected = iconSelected;
    }

    public MyPageBuilder(String pageTitle, int icon, int selectedIcon, Fragment frag) {
        this.pageTitle = pageTitle;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.iconSelected = selectedIcon;
        this.fragment = frag;
    }
}

public static class MyPageArrayList extends ArrayList<MyPageBuilder> {
    private final String logTAG = MyPageArrayList.class.getName() + ".";

    public MyPageBuilder get(Class cls) {
        // Fragment über FragmentClass holen
        for (MyPageBuilder item : this) {
            if (item.fragment.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cls.getName())) {
                return super.get(indexOf(item));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getTag(int viewPagerId, Class cls) {
        // Tag des Fragment unabhängig vom State z.B. nach bei Orientation change
        for (MyPageBuilder item : this) {
            if (item.fragment.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cls.getName())) {
                return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + indexOf(item);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So just create a MyPageArrayList with the fragments:

```
    myFragPages = new MyPageAdapter.MyPageArrayList();

    myFragPages.add(new MyPageAdapter.MyPageBuilder(
            getString(R.string.widget_config_data_frag),
            R.drawable.ic_sd_storage_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_sd_storage_selected_24dp,
            new WidgetDataFrag()));

    myFragPages.add(new MyPageAdapter.MyPageBuilder(
            getString(R.string.widget_config_color_frag),
            R.drawable.ic_color_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_color_selected_24dp,
            new WidgetColorFrag()));

    myFragPages.add(new MyPageAdapter.MyPageBuilder(
            getString(R.string.widget_config_textsize_frag),
            R.drawable.ic_settings_widget_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_settings_selected_24dp,
            new WidgetTextSizeFrag()));
```

and add them to the viewPager:

```
    mAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), myFragPages);
    myViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

after this you can get after orientation change the correct fragment by using its class:

```
        WidgetDataFrag dataFragment = (WidgetDataFrag) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(myFragPages.getTag(myViewPager.getId(), WidgetDataFrag.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit different opinion instead of storing the Fragments yourself just leave it to the FragmentManager and when you need to do something with the fragments look for them in the FragmentManager:

```
//make sure you have the right FragmentManager 
//getSupportFragmentManager or getChildFragmentManager depending on what you are using to manage this stack of fragments
List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
if(fragments != null) {
   int count = fragments.size();
   for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
       Fragment fragment = fragments.get(x);
       //check if this is the fragment we want, 
       //it may be some other inspection, tag etc.
       if (fragment instanceof MyFragment) {
           //do whatever we need to do with it
       }
   }
}
```

If you have a lot of Fragments and the cost of instanceof check may be not what you want, but it is good thing to have in mind that the FragmentManager already keeps account of Fragments.

Answer (score -32):

add:

```
   @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
```

before your class.

it it doesn´t work do something like this:

```
@SuppressLint({ "ValidFragment", "HandlerLeak" })
```