# Android - Fragment screen rotate

Tags: android, screen-orientation, fragment, android-viewpager

I'have 1 FragmentActivity with a ViewPager which handle 2 Fragments.

public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

`private Fragment f1;
private Fragment f2;
private ViewPager myPager;
private MyFragmentAdapter mFragmentsAdapter;
private static ArrayAdapter<Fragment> mFragmentArray;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle); 
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); 
myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_acciones);

mFragmentArray = new ArrayAdapter<Fragment>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
f1 = new Fragment();
    f1 = new Fragment();

mFragmentArray.add(f1);
mFragmentArray.add(f2);

mFragmentsAdapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
myPager.setAdapter(mFragmentsAdapter);
myPartidoPager.setCurrentItem(0);


}


public static class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public AccionesFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mFragmentArray.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return mFragmentArray.getItem(position);
    }


}`

My problem is that every time the screen orientation changes, the activity is created and also the Fragments. I don't mind if the activity is created again, but I don't want the Fragments to be recreated.

Comment: I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state) Thanks @oneilse14 for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to throw a `if` statement right after the on create method is called and check to see if you already have something in there. If `savedInstanceState` is not null, you don't need to do anything:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null){
  // do whatever 
} else {
  // dont do anything
}
```

(this answer is more for people that stumble upon this question cause they can't figure out why fragments get re-added every time they turn their device)

Answer (score 4):

You could add:
`android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"`
In `AndroidManifest.xml`.

This will prevent Android calling `onCreate` on screen orientation change. If you want to perform special handling of orientation change, you can override `onConfigurationChanges`.

Comment: Can't believe these answers are still posted here. Better have a look at this: http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/09/25/deep-dive-into-android-state-restoration/

Comment: One of the most significant drawbacks to this approach is that by not calling onCreate, Android won't be given a chance to load different layouts for landscape and portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Save your FragmentAdapter in onSaveInstanceState and return it to the Activity after a configuration change with onRetainNonConfigurationInstance so the fragments survive an orientation change.

Comment: @oneilse12. Thank you. But with a FragmentActivity it is not possible to override onRetainNonConfigurationInstance method.