# ViewPager with one page containing multiple Fragments "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my small Android app, I have a `ViewPager` with 3 pages, each page contains one fragment, that's all working fine with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (see [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13597181/347565)).

Now for larger screens, I would like to keep a `ViewPager`, but I want the first two fragments to be on the same first page.

For this, I implement my own PagerAdapter and this is mostly working, the only problem I am trying to resolve is when I am rotating the screen, I get an error:

```
12-11 16:34:13.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.matthieu/com.matthieu.TestActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030002 (com.matthieu:id/top_fragment) for fragment TestFragment{481a3a98 #0 id=0x7f030002}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3815)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030002 (com.matthieu:id/top_fragment) for fragment TestFragment{481a3a98 #0 id=0x7f030002}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1861)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
        ... 12 more
```

I put a sample code simulating what I am trying to do (and showing this error message) on [GitHub](https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/fragment_layout).

I guess one problem I have is because of the Fragments I have in the real application, I cannot really have a `static newInstance` constructor, but instead the Fragments are created ahead of time and have 'setRetainInstance(true);' set.

I understand the id of the `viewGroup` that will contain the fragment [should be part of the hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8158916/347565), and eventually, I guess, it is...

If it makes any difference, I am using the support library and the SherlockActionBar to maintain backwards compatibility with older devices.

Any idea on how to go about this?

**EDIT**: I have found that if I remove the Fragments from the `FragmentManager` in `onSaveInstanceState` I am not getting any crash anymore. All the fragments are recreated from scratch which is not what I want, but I guess I might have to do this and somehow recover those fragments later....

Comment: I outlined a few approaches for solving your original problem here: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Mark, thanks for your attention :) I actually read that blog post before. I think only the second approach would work since I am partitioning the page horizontally. I will read again that page and see if I can pick some ideas from there.

Comment: @CommonsWare none of those different approaches work.. the closest one is the 2nd one, but it does not include Fragments in the pages, only simple widgets... I tried everything I could and running out of ideas. Unless somebody really has some good idea, I'll have to go another way about this.

Comment: "the closest one is the 2nd one, but it does not include Fragments in the pages, only simple widgets" -- that blog post was written before nested fragments were added. Nested fragments can be blended into some of these solutions. Here is a reference to a nested fragment version of the second one from my post:  https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/114205433913370454414/111289811888358912498/posts/J2VaHs6VodE

Comment: Are you using getChildFragmentManager() to next the sub-fragments (as you should)? that goes instead of getFragmentManager() or getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel, please see the answer I posted... I was not using nested fragments initially....

Comment: I know you were using nested fragments, I just wanted to state the obvious to make sure your doing it the proper way. Of course I initially assumed the answer will probably be "of course I did". :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All right, even though I moved to another way of doing things, I don't like to leave things incomplete...

Going the way of the nested Fragments as suggested by Mark. The link posted in the comments goes to 404, but I found your [example code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested) about nested fragments.

A few things I've learned on the way:

- Nested fragments cannot have `setRetainInstance(true)`, or it will get:

  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't retain fragements that are nested in other fragments
- It was a mistake to create a `FrameLayout` in the page of the `ViewPager` to hold the fragment. Looking in the Android code (and specifically the `FragmentPagerAdapter`), I should just use `container.getId()` to find where to add the `Fragment`. Looks like you cannot do anything more sophisticated at that level or it will break.
- From my understanding, if the fragments hold some information (like I do) that takes a long time to load, the different ways to handle this are:

  - Use `onSaveInstanceState` (preferred way ?), but not possible if the Fragment is nested. The (empty) constructor will get called when needed by the framework.
  - Use `setRetainInstance(true)`, in that case `savedInstanceBundle` is always `null`, but that Fragment (as Java object) will not be destroyed and it will still go through onAttach / onCreateView.
  - Find some other way to save and restore what you need...

Anyway, I pushed my solution using nested fragments on [github](https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/fragment_layout)

Comment: +1 for the "Nested fragments cannot have setRetainInstance(true)"