# fragment partial replacement

Tags: android, fragment

i have 2 fragments with their respective layout. when someone open the application fragment 1 should appear. fragment1 have a button. when the user clicks that button , the fragment1 should slide right partially i.e 80% and at that place 2nd fragment should appear. 20% of the fragment 1 should still be visible. when the user again click that button, the fragment 2 should completely slide to left and and fragment 1 must be visible completely now. please tell me how i can do this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816442/viewpager-with-one-page-containing-multiple-fragments-java-lang-illegalargument see this link

Comment: no this is not my solution . i am not using the Viewpager