# No view found for id 0x for fragment after rotation?

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, fragment, android-support-library

I'm loading some fragments in a container, which holds a Navigation Drawer too.
When rotating the screen, and then rotating it back, the app crashes:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{lu.gian.uniwhere.alfa/com.example.alfa.ActivityHome}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b004e
>   (com.example.alfa:id/taxes_pager) for fragment
>   FragmentTaxToBePaid{b5969898 #2 id=0x7f0b004e}

I got this error when **rotating back** to portrait mode, after going landscape. What's fun is that I'm not loading `FragmentTaxes` (that is, *N.B.*., a `ViewPager`), but totally another fragment (*FragmentOverwiew* - nothing special to note about it)!

It throws the exactly same error when rotating back from FragmentSession, which is a `ViewPager` holder too:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{lu.gian.uniwhere.alfa/com.example.alfa.ActivityHome}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b000f
>   (com.example.alfa:id/session_pager) for fragment
>   FragmentSessionApplied{b5afa300 #1 id=0x7f0b000f}

I've tried **everything** out there (not retaining instances of the fragments, putting them in the back stack, replacing `Frame` xml tag with `FrameLayout`, creating a specific layout for then landscape mode, etc, etc), but hardly anything sorted an effect.
I think it's due to fragments lifecycle, because crashes are inconstant and difficult to debug, but it's quite hard to understand how to fix this sort of problem.

**ActivityHome**

```
public void selectItem(int position) {
        // ...
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mDrawerTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

**activity_home**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    ... >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <!-- The navigation drawer  .... -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**FragmentTaxes**

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_taxes, container, false);
```

**fragment_taxes**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    ... >

    <!-- Loader -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/taxes_main_progress"
        layout="@layout/indeterminate_activity_bar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/taxes_pager"
        ... >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/taxes_pager_tab_strip"
            ... />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If needed I will post more snippets of code. Now I don't, I think it can result confusing for reading.

Answer (score 8):

It was all due to `setRetainInstance(true)`. I thought it was sufficient to set it to false in the two ViewPagers. It wasn't, actually.
I removed it from the single (nested) fragments, and all went well.

It looks like nested fragments can't handle `setRetainInstance`. Got it from here: [ViewPager with one page containing multiple Fragments "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816442/viewpager-with-one-page-containing-multiple-fragments-java-lang-illegalargument)