# Uses of fragment tags

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

In Android, you can set a tag for a Fragment in a FragmentTransaction.

Why would I need to set a tag for a Fragment?

And is it good practice if a Fragment changed its behavior based on its tag?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Fragment tags can be used to avoid recreating a `Fragment` on `Activity` orientation change.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photos_image_pager);

    MyFragment fragment;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        fragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag("my_fragment_tag");
    } else {
        fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "my_fragment_tag")
            .commit(); 
    }
}
```

The `Activity` is recreated on orientation change, and its `onCreate(...)` method is called. If the `Fragment` was created before the `Activity` was destroyed and was added to the `FragmentManager` with a tag, it can now be retrieved from the `FragmentManager` by the same tag.

For a longer discussion on how it can be used, see:

- [ViewPager and fragments - what's the right way to store fragment's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state)

Comment: I'm sorry, I kind of forgot I asked this. Thank you for the info, but what I'm asking is should I be using the tag to determine what content the fragment should display?

Answer (score 2):

### For Non-UI Fragments:

> Why would I need to set a tag for a Fragment?

Sometimes the `Fragment` can be used as a background worker by the `Activity`. Such fragment doesn't have UI, it is also called non-UI fragment. The `String tag` is the only way to identify this fragment. To add this fragment, you use `add(Fragment, String)` method which doesn't take `View Id`. For example:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
workFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
fm.beginTransaction().add(workFragment, "work").commit();
```

Then later, to get the reference to this fragment use,

```
workFragment = (WorkFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag("work");
```

Now using the `workFragment` reference you can access all the methods of this fragment in the `Activity` or it's UI fragment. [Here's](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.java) the complete example of a non-UI fragment.

---

### For Fragments with UI:

> And is it good practice if a Fragment changed its behaviour based on
>   its tag?

There are situations where we have to change the fragment's behaviour from `Activity` using tags. It should be alright to do so, I've seen some open source apps using this practice. Basically you supply string tags to fragments. This is used for tagging a fragment within the `FragmentManager` so we can easily look it up later. And change or access it's behaviour from the `Activity`.

For example:
A user switches to `SettingsActivity` from `MainActivity`, changes the setting, presses back button to come back to MainActivity. You can detect the setting change in MainActivity#onResume() and update or change the behaviour of the current fragment according to the new setting.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
uiFragment = (UiFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("ui");
uiFragment.fetchNewData();
uiFragment.displayNewData();
```