# Can you detach a fragment in onDestroy()?

Tags: android

Here's the issue I'm having. I've got an activity A that has a fragment F, which is contained in FragmentPagerAdapter FPA, which is in view V. (A->V->FPA->F)

When A gets destroyed (or in this case, swapped out), F is attached, and is in FPA, which is in V. However, when A gets recreated (someone hits the back button back into the activity, for instance), V and FPA don't exist, so F is recreated (in the attached state!), but to something that doesn't exist, so it's not in the view hierarchy at all. Then, when FPA tries to instantiateState on this fragment, it'll try to attach it, which does nothing because it's already attached to thin air.

There are obviously a few ways to fix this (have V and FPA exist in onCreate of the activity, so that the fragment has somewhere to go when it gets created, for instance), but I'd like to continue to lazily create FPA and V only when needed.

Thusly, it seems like updating the state of F to detached in onDestroy() would be desirable. However, state is saved in onPause(), which means I'm kinda out of luck here.

Is there a way to update the saved state of F in A's onDestroy()? Is there a way to say "don't rehydrate this fragment if the activity gets destroyed"? Is there some other obvious way of thinking about this that I'm not considering? It feels like I'm going about things the wrong way here.

Answer (score 1):

I've had my trouble with `FragmentPagers`. What I do is passing a null bundle in the Activity `onCreate()` and then create everything from scratch every time it is created. Like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    // do my stuff
}
```

This way the fragment wont be passed on when the activity is recreated.

Comment: Whew - that's a pretty restrictive solution. Definitely won't work for my activity, which has other fragments (not in the FragmentPagerAdapter) that do need to be restored.

Comment: To still have the state persisted for certain Fragments while using this solution, what I did was to myself programmatically persist the Fragments' state in the Activity's state Bundle. In the Activity's onSaveInstanceState(), I call the Fragment's onSaveInstanceState() to allow the Fragment to add its state to the Bundle. In the Activity's onCreate() where I programmatically create and add the Fragment, I pass the Bundle to Fragment.setArguments(). The Fragment retrieves saved state from the Bundle via its getArguments() in its onCreate(), and ignores the Bundle passed to its onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> Is there some other obvious way of thinking about this that I'm not considering?

This doesn't directly answer your title question but provides a convenient solution to how to preserve `Fragment` state in a `ViewPager`.

You can save the `Fragment` states when the `Activity` is destroyed by tagging the `Fragment` in the `Activity` that initializes the `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photos_pager_activity);

    MyImageFragment fragment;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        fragment = (MyImageFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_image_fragment_tag");
    } else {
        fragment = new MyImageFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "my_image_fragment_tag").commit(); 
    }
```

See also:

[Uses of fragment tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509495/uses-of-fragment-tags)

[ViewPager and fragments — what's the right way to store fragment's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state)

Comment: Yeah, but as those links explain, the ID and tag are set by the FragmentPagerAdapter if you use that.

Comment: Why can't you have the FPA set tags?

Comment: Without rewriting most of it, the FPA has a makeFragmentName function that creates the tag name, and the ID is set to the ID of the container.

Comment: In my tag example, the FPA will work 'out of the box' with no subclassing/re-writes. It will maintain your Fragments state when your Activity is destroyed, and there is no need to re-create the Fragments again. I don't have the full code of your example, and don't know if this will work for you or not, but with the information supplied in your question it would. My answer doesn't address "Can you detach a fragment in onDestroy()?" and the details of that but it provides a (common) solution to your problem. Hope it was of some help:)