# View visibility is not getting restored from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

My Fragment1 xml layout has:

- Two RadioButtons, unchecked by default
- Two EditTexts (One with inputType="decimal" and the other with inputType="number"), having visibility="gone"
- A Button, also with visibility="gone"

So, initially they appear like this:

[image: Screenshot 1 - Two radio buttons, none selected.]

Then on clicking either of the radio buttons, the required EditText and the button is made visible, and I can enter values.

[image: Screenshot 2 - Radio button clicked. One EditText and the button is now visible]

On clicking the button, Fragment1 is replaced with Fragment2. 
Then on pressing the back key, the back stack doesn't restore the visibility information of EditText and Button. It shows the selected radio button, and only after clicking on it I can see the EditText with the previously entered value, and the button.

[image]

I want it to display the entered value along with the button, without having to click the radio options.

My Fragment java:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

// Member variables to store the visibility info of the two EditTexts and the button
int visibilityEditTextArea;
int visibilityEditTextNum;
int visibilityBtnEnterStateRec;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ... 

    // OnClickListener for the first radio button, "Area of Farm".
    // Sets the visibility of the EditText with inputType="decimal" and the button to be VISIBLE, 
    // and intializes the member variables with the new visibility info.
    RadioButton radioButtonArea = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_area_of_farm_to_fertilize);
    radioButtonArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Activity activity = getActivity();

            EditText editTextArea = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText_area);
            if (editTextArea.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                editTextArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                visibilityEditTextArea = editTextArea.getVisibility();
            }

            EditText editTextNum = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText_number);
            if (editTextNum.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                editTextNum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                visibilityEditTextNum = editTextArea.getVisibility();
            }

            Button btnEnterStateRec = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_enter_state_rec);
            if (btnEnterStateRec.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                btnEnterStateRec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                visibilityBtnEnterStateRec = btnEnterStateRec.getVisibility();
            }
        }
    });

    // Similarly for the second radio button.
    RadioButton radioButtonNum = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_number_of_plants);
    radioButtonNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Activity activity = getActivity();

            EditText editTextArea = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText_area);
            if (editTextArea.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                editTextArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                visibilityEditTextArea = editTextArea.getVisibility();
            }

            EditText editTextNum = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText_number);
            if (editTextNum.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                editTextNum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                visibilityEditTextNum = editTextArea.getVisibility();
            }

            Button btnEnterStateRec = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_enter_state_rec);
            if (btnEnterStateRec.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                btnEnterStateRec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                visibilityBtnEnterStateRec = btnEnterStateRec.getVisibility();
            }
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Button, "ENTER STATE RECOMMENDATIONS".
    // Puts the member variables in a bundle, and then replaces the container with Fragment2
    Button buttonEnterStateRec = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_enter_state_rec);
    buttonEnterStateRec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Puts the member variables in a bundle before making fragment transaction
            Bundle outState = new Bundle();
            outState.putInt("visibility_eT_area", visibilityEditTextArea);
            outState.putInt("visibility_eT_num", visibilityEditTextNum);
            outState.putInt("visibility_btn_enterStateRec", visibilityBtnEnterStateRec);
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            fragment1.setArguments(outState);

            Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });


    // Restores the member variables with the arguments from the bundle
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        visibilityEditTextArea = args.getInt("visibility_eT_area");
        visibilityEditTextNum = args.getInt("visibility_eT_num");
        visibilityBtnEnterStateRec = args.getInt("visibility_btn_enterStateRec");

        // Checks if the int value of the member variable equals to that of View.VISIBLE.
        // If it does then sets the respective View to be visible.
        if (visibilityEditTextArea == View.VISIBLE) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.editText_area).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (visibilityEditTextNum == View.VISIBLE) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.editText_number).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (visibilityBtnEnterStateRec == View.VISIBLE) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.btn_enter_state_rec).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    return view;
}

// Overides onPause() to save the visibility arguments in a bundle.
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Bundle outState = new Bundle();
    outState.putInt("visibility_eT_area", visibilityEditTextArea);
    outState.putInt("visibility_eT_num", visibilityEditTextNum);
    outState.putInt("visibility_btn_enterStateRec", visibilityBtnEnterStateRec);
    Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    fragment1.setArguments(outState);
}
```

}

The XML is like this. I've removed the IDs and the layout alignment details.:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    ...
    <RadioGroup>

        <RadioButton
            android:text="Area of farm to fertilize" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="Number of plants or trees" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <EditText
            android:hint="In hectare"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <EditText
            android:inputType="number"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="Enter state recommendations"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by implementing a **setOnCheckedChangeListener** on the radio buttons. OnClickListener doesn't give the required behaviour with [Compound Buttons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html) like checkboxes, radio buttons, switches and toggle buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, current implementation of `FragmentActivity` (or `AppCompatActivity`) will do the dirty work of restoring view states for you, all you have to do is give your `Fragment` an id or a tag.

So, when adding your **first** fragment (or any fragment you want to be subject to automatic view state retaining) do this:

```
// probably in onCreate() of your activity:
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Note the 3rd parameter -- it's the tag
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1, "FRAGMENT1");
```

Now it'll be restored, when you pop the frag2-frag1 transaction off the back stack.

And in `onActivityCreated()` you can go like this:

```
public View onActivityCreated(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // pick up stuff from savedInstanceState
        // this is for the cases when onSaveInstanceState() has been called
        // i.e. for when activity's onSaveInstanceState() has been called
        // not for back stack events
    }
```

And move your `onPause()`/`onCreateView()` bundle manipulations to `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onActivityCreated()` -- all other cases will be automatically handled by `FragmentManager`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the tag param. It was missing from my add(). (More info on the importance of tags in fragments over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13510619/1944049 ) It still doesn't restore the visibility state though. I guess I'll have to alter my design.