# How to implement view pager in a screen with four fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The app for tablet for each screen into four parts(four fragment). I have added four fragment to fragments transaction in a single layout. Now I have to implement view pager in that. How can I achieve that. Using that view pager library I have to pass the fragment manager and fragmentlist as argument. In my scenario How can I pass every 4 argument in a single time?

My Main Activity was:

```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         NewsFragment[]
> newsFragment_obj = new NewsFragment[GlobalValues.titile.length];
> 
>       fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
> 
>       for (int i = 0; i < GlobalValues.titile.length; i++) {
>           newsFragment_obj[i] = new NewsFragment(GlobalValues.titile[i],
>                   GlobalValues.content[i]);       }
> 
>       fragMentTra.add(R.id.fragment_container1, newsFragment_obj[0],
>               "Fragment1");       fragMentTra.add(R.id.fragment_container2, newsFragment_obj[1],
>               "Fragment2");       fragMentTra.add(R.id.fragment_container3, newsFragment_obj[2],
>               "Fragment3");       fragMentTra.add(R.id.fragment_container4, newsFragment_obj[3],
>               "Fragment4");
> 
>       fragMentTra.commit();   }
```

This is how I have added the four fragment to the screen. Now only am looking into view pager. So could you please tell  me how can I achieve that with view pager with example code.

My XML File was:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/upper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/up_left_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff66" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/up_right_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ccffff" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lower"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/down_left_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#66cc33" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/down_right_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cc6600" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make a wrapper fragment, and use nested fragments? (these were introduced in the new support lib)

Comment: @user1281750  Could u been explain elaborately. Again conform my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `FragmentTransactions` at all. Have a look at [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) if you want to have 4 'swipable' screens with each screen as a `Fragment`.

The main thing you want is to get the `ViewPager` from your XML:

`mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);`

Then you want to create your custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` by extending `FragmentPagerAdapter` and defining the construction of the fragments:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS; // In this case, 4
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // This is basically just making a new Fragment
        // e.g. if (position == 0) return new FirstPageFragment()
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

Then make the adapter:

`mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`

Then set the adapter on the `ViewPager`:

`mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

There are a **lot** of gotchas with this. For example, the `ViewPager` handles the setting of fragment tags, so you have to be really careful with Activity recreation (see [ViewPager and fragments — what's the right way to store fragment's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state) for a discussion on this).

There are also a lot of things you will need to think about. Do you want to keep Fragments if they are off screen? What about if you only want some? Look into [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) and [ViewPager.setOffscreenLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

Comment: No No.. This is not my scenario. I want to divide a single screen into four parts. Fill each part with fragment. I want the consecutive screens also like this.

Comment: Your answer for the scenario of each screen with single fragment. But for my scenario table, each screen with four fragments.