# Attempt to refresh fragment gives me NullPointerException; I've made sure compatibility isn't an issue, and my fragments shouldn't be null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragmentmanager

I am currently trying to implement code in my android project where my fragments will refresh after a button is pressed, recreating the view and displaying different items. I made sure there were no compatibility issues between android.app and android.support.v4.app, and am positive that I have my fragments' id's labelled correctly.

Here is the exact error I received when running my app on an emulator:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int      android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:722)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

And here is the java code that is causing the issue in its class:

```
package edu.sbu.cs.android.NMR.core;
import edu.sbu.cs.android.NMR.core.ImageAdapter;
import edu.sbu.cs.android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
     public interface OnSelectedListener {
           public void onSelected();
      }
    OnSelectedListener mListener;
     @Override
       public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
           super.onAttach(activity);
      try {
           mListener = (OnSelectedListener) activity;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
           throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
       }
   }

GridView gridview;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
  gridview = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(gridview.getContext()));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setProblem(position);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    SpectraFragment.w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nmr0.html");
                    getArguments().putString("problem", "0");
                    FragmentManager fragMan;
                    fragMan = getFragmentManager();
                    Fragment frg= fragMan.findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_spectra);
                    Fragment frg2 = fragMan.findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_questions);
                    final FragmentTransaction ft = fragMan.beginTransaction();
                    ft.detach(frg);
                    ft.attach(frg);
                    ft.detach(frg2);
                    ft.attach(frg2);
                    ft.commit();

                case 1:
                    SpectraFragment.w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nmr1.html");
                    getArguments().putString("problem", "1");
                    fragMan = getFragmentManager();
                    frg = fragMan.findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_spectra);
                    frg2 = fragMan.findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_questions);
                    final FragmentTransaction ft2 = fragMan.beginTransaction();
                    ft2.detach(frg);
                    ft2.attach(frg);
                    ft2.detach(frg2);
                    ft2.attach(frg2);
                    ft2.commit();
                case 2:
                    SpectraFragment.w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nmr2.html");
                    getArguments().putString("problem", "2");
                    fragMan = getFragmentManager();
                    frg = fragMan.findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_spectra);
                    frg2 = fragMan.findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_questions);
                    final FragmentTransaction ft3 = fragMan.beginTransaction();
                    ft3.detach(frg);
                    ft3.attach(frg);
                    ft3.detach(frg2);
                    ft3.attach(frg2);
                    ft3.commit();
                default:
                    SpectraFragment.w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nmr0.html");
            }

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  return rootView;
   }
}
```

Has anyone every had this issue before where the problem wasn't due to compatibility between android.support.v4.app and android.app, or am I missing a point in my code where I am making a null object reference? I've searched these forums for weeks and have tried every solution I can think of. I've even switched out ActionBar tabs in my MainActivity for a material design SlidingTabLayout to get rid of the compatibility issue, but it has done nothing. I'm frustrated as to why my code won't, and although I've been working with android for a year, there are still things that I don't quite understand although I've made a different app that works fine. This one is a bit more complex and was passed to me to work on, so I am still figuring out how some of it works. I'm sorry to have gone off on a rant, but I've been stuck on this issue for a while and seem to be at a dead end. Anyone have any solutions?

Also, I'm using android studio to develop my app if that makes any difference in solving the issue, but I had been previously using eclipse and had moved the project over.

Comment: It's null. Just accept it and debug it.

Comment: I guess I'll have to, I just don't understand why that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
In the `switch` statement, you are missing the `break;` statements on your cases.

A glance at line 722 of the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord.java) for `BackStackRecord` suggests you called `FragmentTransaction.detach()` with a null fragment.  Probably one of your calls to `findFragmentById()` is returning null.  To find out which one, check the result of each call and log a debug message if it is null.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it was helpful I'll  need to look at the source code in the future to help me solve these problems, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` on Fragments that are likely extending `android.app.Fragment`

You have to use `android.app.FragmentTransaction` with `android.app.Fragment` and you have to use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` to make transactions involving `android.app.v4.app.Fragment`

You can't intermix the two. The way to fix it would simply be to change the offending Fragments to extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I swear I've made sure every fragment extends and imports android.support.v4.app fragment. In fact, I replaced the ActionBar.tabs I was using in my main activity because they weren't allowing me to use the android.support.v4.app fragment manager.

Comment: This is likely the solution and has even been confirmed in other questions [such as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489703/trying-to-remove-fragment-from-view-gives-me-nullpointerexception-on-mnextanim). It might help to post the code to your other fragments to get another set of eyes on them. Sometimes when I get frustrated and tunnel myself on a particular problem, I miss silly mistakes that I made. It might help :)

Answer (score 0):

The Error is clearly showing you that it's acted on null object reference, which means no fragment with the corresponding id in that fragment manager.Try either getChildFragmentManager() or getParentFragment() which worked for me.