# How to refesh fragment when delete data from DB

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have below code for data remove from DB.
So i delete data but i want to update fragment from here.

how i can refesh fragment ?

```
 // Remove entry from database table
                database.delete(FAVORITES_TABLE, FAVORITES_ITEM_ID + " = " + soundObject.getItemID(), null);

// Refesh current fragment 
????????????????????????????????
```

this is code which i use in Fragment to refesh it (on button press) work good, but i don't want to tap refesh button to refesh page. I want fragment refesh when DB change by it self.

```
 public void refersh()
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
```

any idea?
Thanks

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702418/3395198

Comment: use a handler to refresh your fragment when ever you cahnge the database

Answer (score 0):

you are detaching and attaching again in one commit, so it does nothing. make it two commits

```
public void refersh(){
    FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft1.detach(this).commit();
    FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft2.attach(this).commit();
}
```

there is also possibility that you shoud use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`

its probably not best/most-efficient solution, but you posted ony this small snippet...

Comment: hmm, i mean that i want update fragment not from buttom press, but when db change.

Comment: make some interface, which will call `refersh()` method (yes, with typeo)

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms you can use:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Comment: but only if im calling this fucntion from huntle. but i have evenhandlerclass and i want to call it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to refresh the fragment contents upon DB data updates

If so, *detach* the fragment and again *attach* it

```
// Reload current fragment
   Fragment f1 = null;
   f1 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_TAG");
   final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.detach(f1);
   ft.attach(frg);
   ft.commit();
```

Fragment_TAG is the name you gave your fragment when you created it

Comment: ok, so i have item menu with remove file action. (when i tap remove file is removed from DB, but fragment is not refeshed)  where i should put your code? thx

Comment: When you calling the remove file operation from fragment then call the above code from there.

Comment: `int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mContainerId' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1017)` getting this error :(

Comment: please check  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489703/trying-to-remove-fragment-from-view-gives-me-nullpointerexception-on-mnextanim) for your error may be this help you out... (Y)

Answer (score 0):

To **refresh** the current fragment content, you can use the following code inside the method `refresh()`

```
public void refresh()
   {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new Current_Fragment_Name(); //replace the  Current_Fragment_Name with your current fragment name
            FragmentTransaction ft =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
   }
```

Hope it works for you.