# How to save the state of a fragment in viewpager if I use fragments this way?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I would like to save the state of a fragment in a viewpager. I know that I should do it this way: [ViewPager and fragments — what's the right way to store fragment's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state) . But I use fragments this way:

**MyAdapter**

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public List<String> fragmentsA; //plus

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentsA = fragments;//plus
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //return MyFragment.newInstance();
            return Fragment.instantiate(context, fragmentsA.get(position));

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            //return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
            return mEntries.get(position % CONTENT.length).toUpperCase();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
           // return CONTENT.length;
            return mEntries.size();
        }

       @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
       }

    }
```

**HostActivity**

```
 public static List<String> fragments = new Vector<String>();

@Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {

pager = (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById( R.id.indicator );
pager.setAdapter( adapter );
indicator.setViewPager( pager );
pager.setCurrentItem(INITIAL_PAGE);

//mEntries.add...

    fragments.clear();
    fragments.add( Tab1Fragment.class.getName());
    fragments.add( Tab2Fragment.class.getName());
    fragments.add( Tab3Fragment.class.getName());
    fragments.add( Tab4Fragment.class.getName());

}
```

How can I save the fragmens state this way? I mean I need this method:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .putFragment(outState, MessagesFragment.class.getName(), mMessagesFragment);

}
```

So where should I check for every fragment that `if (savedInstanceState != null)` ? And how should I put the fragments into the "outstate" ?

**UPDATE**
So I put the on save state code to every fragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    setUserVisibleHint(true);
    getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, Tab1Fragment.class.getName(), this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the on save state code have to be put inside each fragment class that you use. So for your case it's inside:

Tab1Fragment, Tab2Fragment, Tab3Fragment & Tab4Fragment

Comment: I put the code to every fragment (see updated code), how can I use them now to load the state?

Comment: I've just had a quick look on that link you post and that guys solution is stupid and shouldn't be used. The Bundle on the onSaveInstanceState is to be used to save basic values that is the state of your fragment (e.g. scroll position, current selected, index) stuff like this. And then during onCreateView the 'savedInstance' bundle contains all the values you saved and you can restore them. That's all handled by the system for you and you shouldn't be doing fragment transactions or setting userHint during onSaveInstanceState

Comment: So what do you suggest? If I use FragmentPagerAdapter instead of fragmentstatepageradapter, all the views will be loaded in the memory (which had been loaded before) so it remembers the position. However I have almost 20 fragments with listviews inside all of them and I am not certain about the memory usage after having stored 20 fragments at the same time. This is why I turned to fragmentstatepager adapter as it destroys the views. Do you think the system will be able to handle 20 fragments without any heap errors?

Comment: no. But you use the outState to save stuff. It's a bundle, just like any normal bundle. Inside `onSaveInstanceState` you call outState.putInt, outState.putString, to save what you need.