# Fragment Pager Adapter and Pager View loading next fragment in background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-pageradapter

i am using Fragment Pager Adapter and PagerView to create swipe tab.
 But facing some problem.

Here is my:-ViewPagerAdapter

Its showing first fragment and also showing second fragment dialog
 box(loading data in background). When i swipe to second
 fragment it loads third fragment dialogbox and load data in background.

> ```
> public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
>   private Context _context;
>
>   public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
>       super(fm);
>       _context = context;
>
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
>       Fragment f = new Fragment();
>       switch (position) {
>       case 0:
>           f = ReservationTab.newInstance(_context);
>           break;
>       case 1:
>           f = GalleryTab.newInstance(_context);
>           break;
>       case 2:
>           f = VideoTab.newInstance(_context);
>           break;
>       }
>       return f;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public int getCount() {
>       return 3;
>   }
>
> }
> ```

And accessing from here:--

```
private void setUpView() {
    _mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    _adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
    _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

private void setTab() {
    _mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("PRINT position--  " + position);
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                first_tab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                second_tab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                third_tab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;

            case 1:
                first_tab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                second_tab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                third_tab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case 2:
                first_tab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                second_tab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                third_tab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
        }

    });

}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7951730/1396082)

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behaviour.

If you don't want ViewPager to load next fragment in background you should invoke setOffscreenPageLimit(0).

See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29

Comment: That's not true. If you check the source code for setOffscreenPageLimit(), even if you pass 0 to it, it uses 1.