# Android - How to restore state of ViewPager's items

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble with restoring state of a `View` inside a `ViewPager`. The content of the `ViewPager` is a view extending `FrameLayout`.

The problem is the `FrameLayout.onRestoreInstanceState()` is not being called if added programmatically into the `ViewPager`

Here's the code of my `Activity.java`

```
private ViewPager vPager;
private MainPagerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    // all the findViewById stuff

    CustomView cv1 = new CustomView(this);
    CustomView cv2 = new CustomView(this);

    cv1.setId(R.id.custom_view_id_1);
    cv2.setId(R.id.custom_view_id_2);

    mAdapter = MainPagerAdapter();
    mAdapter.addView(cv1);
    mAdapter.addView(cv2);
    vPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

`MainPagerAdapter` is a class from the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager)

Source code for `CustomView.java`

```
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState() called");
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState() called");
}
```

Here's my findings so far:

1. `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called but `onRestoreInstanceState()` is not
2. When I tried to add the View directly to the root of the Activity, it calls both functions.
3. I found out that Activity's onRestoreState function will be called before the `ViewPager` calls the adapter's `instantiateItem()` function. So when the activity restore its state, the `ViewPager` doesn't have any children yet, thus the savedState doesn't belong to anyone

So I figure out that I need to make one of two things to work:

1. Make sure the `ViewPager` instantiate the item before trying to restore the state, or
2. Calls the CustomView's `onRestoreInstanceState()` manually.

I somehow managed to make option number 2, but is there any way to do option number 1?

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this? I'm facing the same problem...

Comment: @sockeqwe For now I'll only able to do no. 2 which is calls the CustomView's onRestoreInstanceState manually with providing the state from SparseArray.

Comment: Looks like this is an intended behaviour of ViewPager, and in it is worked around with Fragments in FragmentStatePagerAdapter, when fragments aren't really removed.

Would love to see some proper solution when ViewPager is with Views, not Fragments

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question, you can save your ViewPager items state using `mPage.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);` 4 is the number of my Fragments inside ViewPager.

Comment: Doing this does not solve the problem. Calling `.setOffscreePageLimit(int)` means the fragments will be retained even though it's not displayed on screen. Imagine if the number of fragment is big (tens or hundreds) then the performance hit will occur.

Comment: Ok, so what you want? Because I don't understand your question, what you mean saying restore state of ViewPager's items

Comment: It's basically how to utilize `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` like the one in `Activity`, but this one on a custom `ViewGroup`'s state when being put inside `ViewPager`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013996/where-to-restore-fragment-state-that-is-inside-viewpager/31018943 .   Try this, I think this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. But I think that's for fragment while my case is for ViewGroup.

Comment: Ok, so saying save state of viewGroup, you want example if you destroy your app, when viewPager was in second fragment, and you open your app again, it opened second fragment instead of first? Am i understood you?

Comment: Not that. First, look at my findings point (all 3 of them). Second, I'm using `ViewGroup` not a fragment. Third, what I want to achieve is to save the state of the individuals `ViewGroup`, not the position of the selected item.

Comment: SharedPreferences can help you?