# How to communicate with fragments when using viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm currently working with an application that has "swipey-tabs" and uses the following PagerAdapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ListFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ChartFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 3;
    }

}
```

I'm using the following code to communicate with one of my fragments from the main activity:

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1)
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                String className = data.getExtras().getString("class_name");
                if (className.trim().length() > 0) {
                    HomeFragment homeFrag = (HomeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.home_fragment);
                    if(homeFrag != null) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "homeFrag is not null");
                        homeFrag.newClass(className);
                    }else{
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "homeFrag is null");
                        HomeFragment newFragment = new HomeFragment();

                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.home_fragment, newFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        newFragment.newClass(className);
                    }
                    addSubjectToDataBase(className);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when I try to communicate with the fragment from the main activity, I seem to get multiple fragments existing at the same time. When I change the orientation of the screen or restart the activity, I get the modified version of the fragment, but when I swipe back and forth to view the fragments, I get the old, non-modified version of the fragment. The fragment manager doesn't seem to be registering the fragments created by the adapter because though I know the fragments have been created, the fragment manager always returns a null home fragment.

How should I go about avoiding this problem, and what is the best way to communicate with the fragment from the main activity?

Comment: why do you use `OnActivityResult()`?

Comment: The information that I'm updating the fragment with is coming from user input from another activity that is launched when they press an add button.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state/9646622#9646622) I worked out a solution to my own question. The problem was that since `FragmentPagerAdapter` manages its own fragments, the fragment that I was trying to access wasn't the same as the one being used by the view pager.

I worked out a way of accessing the tags of the fragments that are used by the view pager by modifying my modifying my `PagerAdapter` as such:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    protected String homeTag;
    protected String listTag;
    protected String chartTag;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                Log.d("Adapter", "returning new homeFragment");
                return new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ListFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ChartFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                homeTag = createdFragment.getTag();
                break;
            case 1:
                listTag = createdFragment.getTag();
                break;
            case 2:
                chartTag = createdFragment.getTag();
                break;
        }

        return createdFragment;
    }

    public String getHomeTag(){
        return  homeTag;
    }

    public String getListTag(){
        return listTag;
    }

    public String getChartTag(){
        return chartTag;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 3;
    }

}
```

Then, it was a simple matter to modify my code to access the correct fragments after I had access the proper fragment tags:

```
HomeFragment homeFrag = (HomeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mAdapter.getHomeTag());
                    if(homeFrag != null) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "homeFrag is not null");
                        homeFrag.newClass(className);
                    }else{
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "homeFrag is null");
                        HomeFragment newFragment = new HomeFragment();

                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.pager, newFragment, madapter.get);
                        transaction.commit();
                        newFragment.newClass(className);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant but I would do something like this (Maybe someone will post a better solution):

In a singleton, I'll put an array of fragment:

```
public static Fragment[] sShownFragments = new Fragment[3];
```

Then in the `getItem()` method:

```
if(SingletonClass.sShownFragments[index]!=null){
    return mFragments[index];
}

switch (index) {
        case 0:
            SingletonClass.sShownFragments[index] = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            SingletonClass.sShownFragments[index] = new ListFragment();
        case 2:
            SingletonClass.sShownFragments[index] = new ChartFragment();
        default:
            SingletonClass.sShownFragments[index] = new Fragment();
}
return SingletonClass.sShownFragments[index];
```

Then in the `getCount()`:
    return SingletonClass.sShownFragments.length();

Now in your `onActivityResult()`:

```
 \\some code ...
 ((HomeFragment)SingletonClass.sShownFragments[0]).newClass(className);
 \\ some other code...
```