# Android ViewPager orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have read from **@antonyt's** answer to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state) that `FragmentPagerAdapter` will try to reuse an existing fragment found by `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()` upon orientation change.

I have tried this. `getItem(int)` of the `FragmentPagerAdapter` is called when the `Fragment` is first needed. Upon orientation change, `getItem` is not called, which is in accordance with **@antonyt's** answer. But why is it that `onCreate()` of the `Fragment` is called again? I thought it was not destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fragments which not set `setRetainInstance(true)` are destroyed on orientation change. After orientation changed all fragments are recreated and reattach by fragment manager (so fragment goes throught entire lifecycle).

All fragment attached by `ViewPager` are added to fragment manager with special tag. `ViewPager` try to reuse fragment recreated after orientation changed (by searching for tag in fragment manager). If such fragment don't exist then `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)` is called to create new fragment.

Comment: So will a new Fragment with a new tag be added to the FragmentManager? If a new Fragment instance is to be created, why try to find the "old" one from the FragmentManager?

Comment: Tag of recreated fragment stays this same. ViewPager not trying to find "old" fragment (its been destroyed), but recreated fragment (which has this same tag as the old one).