# Saving state of Fragments in a Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Okay I know this has been asked previously but just hear me out !

**ISSUE**

I want to save state of a fragment and then retrieve it in **onCreateView** method .

I have a **ViewPager** in my MainActivity with Four **Fragments** in it .

I have used **viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)** so  fragments does not get recreated if  am in any of two adjacent fragments but if i am in my first fragment and i go to fourth one then fragment first gets recreated .

and if save it in **onSaveInstance** inside fragment then that does not get called until host activity's same method is not called , which will not get called if am just swiping between fragments

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state) also has same problem , it is saving fragments in host activity's  **onSaveInstance** method .So i know how to save fragments state and retrieve it if my host activity gets recreated but what if only fragments gets recreated ?

So How can i save state of a fragment without depending on host activity and then retrieve it in **onCreateView** method of fragment ?

**UPDATE**
Just realized how dumb a person can be , data was there all the time i was not just refilling the views with it .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fragment can't be recreated if activity not recreated in your case.

Comment: @Divers yes my mistake , it is not getting destroyed but onPause is getting called and after that same lifecycle is repeated , oncreate then oncreateview but the problem is that data in fragment which fill the view is getting null , so how do i save and retrieve that ?

Comment: If only onPause() is called, no data would be lost. What exactly is being null?

Comment: @RubenRenzema yeah ....i am stupid ...data is there i am just not reintegrating with views....sorrry to all for wasting your time