# Performance while using Pair in Kotlin for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, tuples

I have been using the following adapter class for `ViewPager`. It was converted to Kotlin from java.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {
    private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentList[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentList.size
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return mFragmentTitleList[position]
    }
}
```

To minimize number of lines I tried using Kotlin **`Pair`**. And convert the above implementation to the following. Now I am curious about the performance of this implementation using `Pair`. Could I get a logical explanation on this?

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {
    private val pairs = ArrayList<Pair<Fragment, String>>()
    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) = pairs.add(Pair(fragment, title))
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = pairs[position].first
    override fun getCount(): Int = pairs.size
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? = pairs[position].second
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to store fragments when using adapter? Maybe you should have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state

Comment: We need to define which fragments should be shown in viewpager, above implementation extending `FragmentPagerAdapter` will facilitate this and do other internal hard works itself. I think this is widely accepted implementation and is used by most people.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Pair` clearly improves readability and maintainability, so go with that.

But I would even go further an use a `Map` instead, if there wasn't the constraint that you need to access the elements via index (`getItem(position: Int)`).

```
private val fragmentToTitleMap = HashMap<Fragment, String>()
```

Add to it:

```
fragmentToTitleMap[someFragment] = "someTitle"
```

---

Don't think too much about micro-optimization. It should not make a noticeable difference in this case, since you won't have +100 Fragments.

Comment: Since we have to use position(int value) which is used in override functions, so I am sticking with the list of Pair and follow your thought on micro-optimization :)