# Fragments not visible when switch tabs using ViewPager and TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I have a `HostActivity` that uses `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` to switch between multiple Fragments. When I switch between the tabs, the Fragments instance does get the updated data. I also see the updated data in `onCreateView` of the `Fragment` instance, but the `TextView.setText` does not get updated. When I check the visibility of `Fragment`, it always shows Invisible. How do I make the fragment visible when I switch tabs so that the view gets updated with new data? Is there something missing in the Fragment/Activity Lifecycle? I am implementing `ViewPager` for the first time so it will be helpful to know if I am missing something.

Fragment Class:

```
public class StepFragment extends Fragment { @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            step = getArguments().getParcelable(SELECTED_STEP);
            mDescription = step.getDescription();
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.step_fragment, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: "+mDescription); **// THIS GETS UPDATED DATA**
        tvStepDescription.setText(mDescription);
        }
        return view;
    }
 }
```

Here is my Host Activity:

```
public class StepActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_step);
        fragmentSelectAdapter = new StepFragmentSelectAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this,steps,recipe);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentSelectAdapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        stepFragment = (StepFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.step_container);
        if(stepFragment == null) {
            stepFragment = StepFragment.newInstance(step, recipe);
            stepFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.step_container, stepFragment)
                    .commit();
        } else {
            stepFragment = StepFragment.newInstance(step, recipe);
            stepFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.step_container, stepFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `FragmentPagerAdapter`, which seems to be getting the correct data as per the tab position in getItem method:

```
public class StepFragmentSelectAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
...
   @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        **// THIS GETS UPDATED DATA**
        Log.e(TAG, "getItem: \nDecr: "+steps.get(position).getDescription()+"\nVideo: "+steps.get(position).getVideoURL()+"\nImage: "+steps.get(position).getThumbnailURL());
        return StepFragment.newInstance(steps.get(position),recipe);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (steps == null){
            return 0;
        }
        return steps.size();
    }
...
}
```

[image: ScreenShot:]

Comment: i think this link would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand about the problem that you are having there, I think you should implement an `onResume` function in your `StepFragment` which will get the updated data from some source and will display this in the `TextView`. However, I can think of a potential problem in your `StepFragmentSelectAdapter`. You are creating a new instance each time you are switching the tabs.

You should have the `Fragment` instances created before and if you are about to pass the data among fragments, you might consider having a `BroadcasReceiver` or listener function by implementing an `interface`.

So the `PagerAdapter` should look something like this.

```
public class StepFragmentSelectAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   public ArrayList<StepFragment> stepFragments;

   public StepFragmentSelectAdapter(ArrayList<Step> steps) {
       stepFragments = new ArrayList<>(); 

       for(int i = 0; i < steps.size(); i++) {
           stepFragments.add(StepFragment.newInstance(steps.get(position),recipe));
       }
   }
...
   @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        **// THIS GETS UPDATED DATA**
        Log.e(TAG, "getItem: \nDecr: "+steps.get(position).getDescription()+"\nVideo: "+steps.get(position).getVideoURL()+"\nImage: "+steps.get(position).getThumbnailURL());
        return stepFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (steps == null){
            return 0;
        }
        return steps.size();
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint. I got around this problem by replacing `ActionBar` with a custom `ToolBar` with back `ImageButton` and using click listener to get back to the calling activity.

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```