# Screen rotation with ViewPager - Problem with FragmentManager and FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having some problems when dealing with Fragment using ViewPager.

**What I'm having:**
An activity (say, `MainActivity`) that contains a `ViewPager` to display some Fragment(s). Some of them contains a callback interface, which will be called to do somethings in the `MainActivity`.
The `MainActivity` has a `FragmentPagerAdapter` class, which is used as the adapter of the `ViewPager`. And a `List<Fragment>` in `FragmentPagerAdapter` to store some Fragment that will be displayed on the `ViewPager`.

**What I'm expecting:**
First launch, the Fragment called the callback interface's methods when I hit a button in it and MainActivity did somethings inside that. It worked great.
After a screen rotation, I expected it to work the same as the first launch **BUT**
*NullPointerException*: attempt to invoke a method on a null reference object (particularly, the Fragment's interface) hit me in my face.

**What I know:**
- The `getItem(int position)` won't be called again once the Fragment is created. Instead the `instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)` will be called.
- `FragmentManager` will store some Fragment in `mActive.mValues`
- [ViewPager and fragments — what's the right way to store fragment's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state/29288093#29288093) (I did reference to this and some other same topics on StackOverflow too.)

**What I have tried and saw:**
- Override `instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)`
- Debugged for 1 day. I saw that when I pass `getSupportFragmentManager()` in MainActivity's `onCreate()` method to `FragmentPagerAdapter`'s super constructor, in the first launch, it has an "address in memory", *assume it was '1a1a1a1'*. The `mActive.mValues` of `FragmentManager` saved some Fragment' "address in memory" which are identical to the `List<Fragment>` containing them (*assume it was 'qwertyu'*). Which meaned it was right.
But when I rotated the screen, passing the `getSupportFragmentManager()` again, the "address in memory" was completely different, assume '9f9f9f9'. And `FragmentManager`'s `mActive.mValues` contained a different set of Fragment' "address in memory" too (*assume **'abcdeff'***), although the number of Fragment in it was equal to the number of Fragment that was saved on the first launch (before rotation).
I have added a Fragment to the `List<Fragment>` with a new "address in memory" (assume 'abababa'), has the callback interface. But when I hit the button in it, it was the Fragment that was in the `FragmentManager`'s `mActive.mValues` after the rotation (with "address in memory" is ***'abcdeff'*** as I assumed above), and that one didn't have the callback interface (due to not being set in `MainActivity` first). And caused the *NullPointerException* as mentioned above.

**My questions now is:**
- First of all, how to get rid of this problem!? It would be better to keep using `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of another class. But I will consider using other class too.
- Second, can you explain why `FragmentManager` saved the Fragment instance before rotation. But after rotation, it creates a completely different Fragment instance but still uses it instead of the Fragment that was saved in the `List<Fragment>`?

Here is the code (I think I didn't use the `instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)` method in the right way so it still caused the problem).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Attach the SectionsPagerAdapter to the ViewPager
        SectionsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }


    //
    //
    //Adapter class
    private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static final int PAGE_HOME = 0;
        private int tabCount = 1;
        private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        //private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

        SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            //fragmentManager = fm;

            //Default HomeFragment
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            //Callback interface
            homeFragment.setOnCategoryFragmentChangedListener(new HomeFragment.OnCategoryFragmentChangedListener() {
                //This method will be called when a button in HomeFragment is clicked
                @Override
                public void onAddNewCategory(String categoryName) {
                    addNewCategory(categoryName);
                }
            });
            fragmentList.add(homeFragment);
            fragmentTitleList.add("Home");
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabCount;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            fragmentList.set(position, (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position));
            return fragmentList.get(position);
        }

        private void addNewCategory(String categoryName) {
            CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();

            tabCount += 1;
            fragmentList.add(fragment);
            fragmentTitleList.add(categoryName);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help. I'm being insane for 2 days now...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, right after i felt in sleep, I found the solution. It's true that I didn't use the `instantiateItem()` method in the right way. After debugging again, I found that the `instantiateItem()` method get call whenever I swipe (or choose if using TabLayout as well) to another Fragment, and even get call before `getItem(int pos)`, no matter what it's the first launch or after rotation. Which is why I think we should set things up for the Fragment in the `instantiateItem()` method.
So here is how I use the `instantiateItem()` method now:

```
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            fragmentList.set(position, (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position));
            Fragment fragment = fragmentList.get(position);
            if (position == PAGE_HOME) {
                ((HomeFragment) fragment).setOnCategoryFragmentChangedListener(new HomeFragment.OnCategoryFragmentChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAddNewCategory(String categoryName) {
                        addNewCategory(categoryName);
                    }
                });
            }
            return fragment;
        }
```

If anyone have a better solution, please just tell me if you don't mind. I will consider about it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe android restarts the activity during orientation change thus making multiple instances of FragmentPagerAdapter and multiple set of instances of List.

I don't completely understand your question but I suspect instantiateItem doesn't do anything anyway. Doesn't the `Fragment getItem(int pos)` work without overriding instantiateItem()?

Comment: Yes, `getItem(int pos)` did work without overriding `instantiateItem()`. But as I said, after screen rotation, `getItem(int pos)` won't be called again on the Fragment(s) that were already created in the first launch. In the code, new HomeFragment instance will be created and added to the `List<Fragment>`; but the ViewPager didn't display that instance (which was added to the `List`), instead it display the instance in `mActive.mValues` of `FragmentManager`, thus caused the NPE.

Comment: My question is about: "How to display Fragment(s) that are NOT from FragmentManager's `mActive.mValues` (but in the new List<Fragment>) after screen rotation? (Additional question: And should I do it like that, by recreating the `List<>` then use it? Is there a better way like recycling or reuse the already created Fragment?")